# How to change password in laravel laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, change-password

I have three fields

1- password
2- new password
3- password_confirmation  this is change password functionality.

I have allow the condition on password that must be 8 characters one upper one lower and one special character

but i cannot change my password its going on my validator fails:

My Controller code:

```
               public function changepassword(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::guard()->user();
    $request_data = $request->All();
    $validator = $this->admin_credential_rules($request_data);
    if($validator->fails()) {
         return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to('mujucet')
            ->with("modal_message_danger", "password must be at least 8 characters, one upper and lower case, and a number");
        } else {

        $current_password = $user->password;
        if(md5($request_data['password']) == $current_password) {
            $user_id = $user->id;
            $obj_user = User::find($user_id);
            $obj_user->password = md5($request_data['new_password']);
            $obj_user->save();

             return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to('mujucet')
                ->with("modal_message_success", "Password has been changed successfully");
        } else {
            return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to('mujucet')
                ->with("modal_message_danger", "wong old password");           
     }
    }
}

               public function admin_credential_rules(array $data){
    $messages = [
        'new_password.required' => "Zdejte novÃ© heslo.",
        'password.required' => "Zadejte souÄasnÃ© heslo.",
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'password' => 'required|min:8|regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/|confirmed',
        'new_password' => 'required|min:8|regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/|confirmed',
    ], $messages);

    return $validator;
}
```

i am stuck into this problem i need your help.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: MD5 is considered broken for security purposes and is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

What errors does the validator give you? You can retrieve them with `$validator->errors()`.

Looking at the code I think you'll need to remove the `confirmed` rule from the password field validator (since you don't need to confirm the old password). Then you'll need to change the new password confirmation field to have the name `new_password_confirmation`.

Your three fields should be: `password`, `new_password` and `new_password_confirmation`.

The validator should be:

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'password' => 'required|min:8|regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/',
        'new_password' => 'required|min:8|regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/|confirmed',
    ], $messages);
```

Have you overridden the default hasher to use MD5 for passwords? By default Laravel uses bcrypt which is a lot more secure for hashing sensitive data.